# How to use <component-scan> for controllers without using @Autowired?

Tags: spring

In a context configuration that uses `<component-scan>` to auto-detect and create `@Controller` beans, I'd like to avoid having to use `@Autowired` annotations on the controller properties (for various reasons I need/prefer to explicitly inject the beans that the controllers need). The controller has property setters marked with `@Required`. How can declare the beans to be injected into the controllers in this scenario?

In other words: Does use of `<component-scan>` necessarily require use of `@Autowired`, and if not, how to accomplish injection of `@Required` properties?

By the way, I was hoping that [Spring component-scan without autowiring?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16115994/spring-component-scan-without-autowiring) would answer my question, but the answer assumes the "clients" (the controllers in my scenario) are not annotated as any kind of `@Component` themselves.

Comment: What do you mean by "manually inject"? Would constructor and field injection not do what you need?

Comment: The only way to avoid autowired is to use a Spring Context file xml using constructor/setter injection.

Comment: As I understand it, you want the instance to be created as a result of @Controller scanning, but at the same time you want `<property name="whatever" ref="someWhateverInstance" />` on your controllers. I don't think that's possible. You don't like `@Autowired` in particular or any other form of auto-wiring (meaning Java config when it comes to injecting dependencies)?

Comment: If you provide more details about "for various reasons I need/prefer to explicitly inject the beans that the controllers need" I'm sure Spring will have some kind of solution that should work for you in a xml-free (and with Java config). For example, you could use `@Qualifier` or `@Resource` instead of `@Autowired`.

Comment: I'm not a fan of autowiring in general, but am not interested in getting into that religious debate here. Suffice it to say that in the particular scenario I'm talking about now, there are a lot of controllers (and other components) discovered via `<component-scan>` and it would be a large piece of work drop it altogether. I'm looking for a solution that will allow me to drop autowiring from a group of them selectively. (unfortunately the ones I want to do that for are not all in the same package).

Comment: And how do you want your injection to be performed? Through xml?

Comment: @AndreiStefan, yes via XML config. That's how the majority of our beans are configured. Would it make a difference if I were willing to accept Java config?

Comment: I don't think you have a choice, actually. If you use component scanning, you tell Spring to create bean instances. If you define a bean in an xml, you tell Spring to create bean instances. If you do this in both ways, you get two bean instances. What you want is Spring creating beans when it sees `@Controller` but then go to the xml and see what dependencies it has. Then what's the point in having component-scanning in the first place, if you still end up doing something with that bean in xml.

Comment: I agree, my perspective is that I don't really want component-scan; however I'm stuck with a code base that uses it and am not interested in totally yanking it out (at this time, but I will eventually). I was hoping there was some way I could leave it in but selectively hand-wire some of the controllers. Kind of like a gradual migration away from component-scan and autowiring. If that's not possible, then convert your last comment to an answer and I'll accept it.

Comment: If that's the case then you can configure component-scanning, with include filters and exclude filters and you get a degree of freedom in what you want scanned and what not. One option is, as the answerer below mentioned is to use an exclude filter based on an annotation, but there are other types as well. See [this section](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/4.0.4.RELEASE/spring-framework-reference/htmlsingle/#beans-classpath-scanning) in the reference documentation about this subject.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you can leave in component-scanning and, at the same time, wiring manually (in XML) the dependencies of the beans being component-scanned.

If you use component scanning, you tell Spring to create bean instances. If you define a bean in an xml, you tell Spring to create bean instances. If you do this in both ways, you get two bean instances. What you want is Spring creating beans when it sees `@Controller` annotation but then go to the xml and see what dependencies it has. Then what's the point in having component-scanning in the first place, if you still end up doing something with that bean in xml?!

If you want selective component-scanning (which is a different matter compared to autowiring only) then you have quite few options. [This section](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/4.0.4.RELEASE/spring-framework-reference/htmlsingle/#beans-scanning-filters) in the reference documentation describes them well.

Answer (score 3):

In your situation, you can gradually move away from component-scan by using an annotation filter to exclude the controllers you want to wire by hand. For example, you could define an @NotAutowired annotation to mark the controllers you want excluded. Then you define the component-scan exclusion filter:

```
@ComponentScan(basePackages = {"app.controller"},
               excludeFilters = @ComponentScan.Filter(
                          value= NotAutowired.class, 
                          type = FilterType.ANNOTATION)
)
```

Or you could simply move the controllers to another package.

Comment: That's a good idea for my particular situation. If SO would let me, I'd accept both answers, but I can't. I think the other answer does a slightly better job of explaining the situation in more general terms, and includes a reference to the component scanning filter documentation. In reality, I probably will use the code in this answer for my particular situation.

Comment: I agree. @AndreiStefan answer and comments actually explained the problem, I just added a particular solution.